# Replace within match of regexp

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to put a text with references I made in Word online.
I have plain text, with references like this `(1)`, `(1,2,5)`, `(1-5)` or a combination: `(1-5,8,10-15)`. I would like to make the numbers a hyperlink to the reference, and put the entire part between `(` and `)` in another HTML-tag.

I found that I can do a regexp to match the parentheses and the numbers with `#(\([0-9,\-]*\))#`, and the numbers in there with `([\(,\-]?(\d{2}|\d)[\),\-])`, but how can I do a replace so that my output is like this?
`!(#1#,#2#-#5#)!`

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Have you tried: `!($1,$2-$3)!` as your replacement parameter, following the details on [php.net](http://uk1.php.net/preg_replace)

Comment: You can optimize this part of your reges `(\d{2}|\d)` to this `(\d{,2})`. Plus what is your expected output?

Comment: Can you show some sample inputs and expected outputs?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for my cryptic description.

What I wanted to do, was make every reference number in my article a link to that reference at the end of my article. References could be formatted as `(1)`, `(1-5)` or `(1,3,5)`, or a combination: `(1-3,5,8-10)`.
The output I wanted was for instance `(<a href="ref-1">1</a>)` and so on.

I figured out I couldn't do that in one find-and-replace, so I had to break it down in two.
This is what I came up with:

```
<?php
$input = "Hello, I am a sample text(1). I have references in me(2-5). They can be in a weird, mixed format(1,3,5-8,10,13)";

function references($input) {
    preg_match_all("#\([0-9,\-]*\)#i", $input, $referenties);
    $tekst = preg_split("#\(([0-9,\-]*)\)#i", $input);
    $referenties = preg_replace("#([\d]+)#", "<a href=\"#ref-$1\">$1</a>", $referenties[0]);

    for($i=0; $i < count($tekst)-1 OR $i < count($referenties)-1; $i++) {
        $output.=$tekst[$i].$referenties[$i];
    }

    return $output;
}

echo references($input);
?>
```

It works for me.
Do you have any thoughts on how I could make this better?